# Как вирусы заражают файлы?

Tags: вирусы

Как вирусы могут заражать файлы .exe, .dll, .com если в них что-то на подобие этого:

Comment: А чем это мешает?

Comment: Тема большая и очень обширная. А то что вы видите - результат использования неправильной смотрелки. Та же IDA покажет куда как больше полезной информации.

Comment: Структура exe файлов отлично описана, каждый "символ" в них поддается декодированию, ибо это инструкции процессора. Изучайте ассемблер и тогда многое станет ясно

Answer (score 13):

В исполняемых файлах находятся наборы инструкций, которые представляют собой определённые последовательности байт. Соответственно замена одного набора инструкций на другой приводит к тому, что программа начинает выполнять не то, что планировалось.